# Why can `qsort` be called with a compare function with the wrong signature and compile has no warnings

Tags: c, void-pointers, qsort

I was working on consolidating a code base (moving a `qsort` `compar` function to a new header /library so that it could be shared without being copy/pasta) and noticed something strange in the process.

Here is a demonstrative listing:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 /** One record has three fields.
 * Each field contains a NULL terminated string of length at most 7 characters. */
typedef char Record[3][8];

int main(void)
{
    Record database[5] = {0};

    strcpy(database[0][0], "ZING");
    strcpy(database[0][1], "BOP");
    strcpy(database[0][2], "POW");

    strcpy(database[1][0], "FIDDLY");
    strcpy(database[1][1], "ECHO");
    strcpy(database[1][2], "ZOOOM");

    strcpy(database[2][0], "AH");
    strcpy(database[2][1], "AAAAA");
    strcpy(database[2][2], "AH");

    strcpy(database[3][0], "BO");
    strcpy(database[3][1], "DELTA");
    strcpy(database[3][2], "FO");

    strcpy(database[4][0], "FRRING");
    strcpy(database[4][1], "CRASH");
    strcpy(database[4][2], "FOO");

    //(gdb) ptype record_compare_field_1
    //type = int (char (*)[8], char (*)[8])
    int record_compare_field_1();
    qsort(database, 5, sizeof(Record), record_compare_field_1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", database[i][0], database[i][1], database[i][2]);
    }
}

/* Compares Records at field one. */
int record_compare_field_1(Record rowA, Record rowB)
{
    return strcmp(rowA[1], rowB[1]);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c
$ ./a.out
AH      AAAAA   AH
ZING    BOP     POW
FRRING  CRASH   FOO
BO      DELTA   FO
FIDDLY  ECHO    ZOOOM
```

It's surprising to me that:

- The compiler has no warnings since the signature of the `compar` function passed to quick sort does not have the prescribed function signature `int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)`. Even in `gdb`, when I run `ptype record_compare_field_1`, it looks like the signature does not contain `const *void`.
- The output is **somehow** correct? (Sorted based on field one (zero-indexed) results in `AAAAA, BOP, CRASH, DELTA, ECHO`.

The questions are:

- Why/how does this work? Is this an old-school way of doing this?
- If I wanted to change the `qsort` `compar` function in use to use the proper signature, how would I do that (I been struggling trying to come up with the proper casts)?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it complain with -Wextra and/or -pedantic?

Comment: MS VC *does* give warnings for this function. The warning is different if I *declare* the function `record_compare_field_1()` but it still warns about the `const` qualifiers.

Comment: gcc version `9.3.0` yields **no complaints** using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.c`.

Comment: The use of function declarators with empty parentheses is an obsolescent feature, but is still allowed by the C17/C18 standard. Passing `record_compare_field_1` to `qsort`s `compar` parameter is allowed by the compatible and composite type rules. However, the code has _undefined behavior_ because the actual `record_compare_field_1` function has the wrong prototype.

Comment: The typedef of `Record` (an array) means that, as an argument, it decays to a pointer ... and any pointer is 'compatible' with `void*`. The declaration `int record_compare_field_1();` indicates an *unspecified* argument list.

Comment: `record_compare_field_1(Record rowA, Record rowB)` is amiss as `qsort` provides 2 addresses of `Record`, not 2 `Record`s.

Comment: @chux The *actual* signature (once defined) is `int record_compare_field_1(char (*a)[8], char (*b)[8])`.

Comment: @AdrianMole Still needs to be `record_compare_field_1(Record *rowA, Record *rowB)`

Comment: Yeah - I guess it's UB but somehow works on most compilers because of how pointers to arrays work.

Comment: Writing sloppy stuff like this is to hide problems underneath the carpet instead of solving them. There is absolutely no guarantee that `int record_compare_field_1(Record rowA, Record rowB)` is compatible with the expected type `int (*) (const void*, const void*)`. This is how you get code with latent bugs that will suddenly crash with no explanation at some point later in time. Aka giving the middle finger to the poor soul who has to maintain the code (very often yourself, in the future).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `int record_compare_field_1();` declaration does not have a prototype. This is an obsolescent feature of the C17/C18 standard.

In the function call `qsort(database, 5, sizeof(Record), record_compare_field_1);`, the `record_compare_field_1` argument has type `int (*)()` and `qsort`'s `compar` parameter has type `int (*)(const void *, const void *)`. This is allowed by this rule from C17 6.2.7:

> — If only one type is a function type with a parameter type list (a function prototype), the composite type is a function prototype with the parameter type list.

The actual `record_compare_field_1` function definition has the prototype `int record_compare_field_1(Record, Record)` where the `Record` type is defined by `typedef char Record[3][8]`. Since array parameters are adjusted to pointers, this is the same as the prototype `int record_compare_field_1(char (*)[8], char (*)[8])`.

`qsort` will call the passed in `record_compare_field_1` function with the wrong prototype, leading to *undefined behavior*. Most C implementations use the same representation for all object pointer types, so it lets you get away with it.

To do it properly, the `record_compare_field_1` function could be defined like this:

```
int record_compare_field_1(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const Record *p_rowA = a;
    const Record *p_rowB = b;
    return strcmp((*p_rowA)[1], (*p_rowB)[1]);
}
```

Comment: Note that you can use GCC's `-Wstrict-prototypes` option to generate a warning when declaring a function without prototype.